# C# Loadl List into textbox WinForms

Tags: c#, list, textbox

I have a problem when I try to display the list into the textbox. It only displays the last line from the list.txt file.  I think for each new line it overwrites the first line from the textbox all the time ? thus showing only the last line from the file ?

what is it I need to think of to get it right ?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            const string f = "list.txt";

            List<string> myList = new List<string>();

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    myList.Add(line);
                }
            }


            foreach (string s in myList)
            {

                textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, s);

            }


        }
```

Comment: is the textbox set to `MultiLine`

Comment: Yes. it is multiline .

Comment: here is something that you can try to test to see if you are getting data `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,myList.ToArray()));` also you are overwritng the TextBox1.Text perhaps you should try `textBox`.Text += string.Join(Environment.NewLine, s);`

Comment: well think about it in your for each you are overwriting the Text, you are not appending or concatenating the data at all..

Comment: You could simplify the entire method down to: `textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadLines("list.txt"));`  Or `textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("list.txt");`

Comment: Servy that's totally worthy of an acceptable answer I'd give it an UPVOTE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this:

> foreach (string s in myList)
>   {
>         textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, s);
>   }

Try:

> textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myList);

And also make sure multiline property of textbox1 is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Because every time, you assign directly to the Text property which will remove the previous one . Here is the fix . Make Multiline of textbox true.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            const string f = "list.txt";

            List<string> myList = new List<string>();

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    myList.Add(line);
                }
            }

            var listString = new StringBuilder()
            foreach (string s in myList)
            {
                listString.Append(Environment.Newline)
                listString.Append(s);              

            }
             textBox1.Text = listString.ToString();

        }
```

Comment: This can be done with one line of code opposed to using the foreach to iterate thru the Lsit<T> of string

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment you can do this in one simple line by eliminating the foreach loop

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myList.ToArray());
```

or just use the myList works the same

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myList);
```

Comment: The `ToArray` isn't needed in .NET 4.0+, and based on his code he's using at least 4.0.

Comment: I know but I added the second example as well the answer will be useful for someone who may fine the first example useful